# Change the spacing in R dendrograms

Tags: r, plot, dendrogram

I want to create a nice dendrogram for my cluster. Since I work with over thousands of data entries, the resulting dendrogram looks kinda sad. The Screenshots show, that too much space is used to display the splits, while not enough space is left to show the important information at the bottom.

[image]

[image: Zoom of picture 1]

[image: Zoom of picture 2]

I want to compress the space used for for the graph display and increase the space used for the labels. Is there an option for this? If I only decrease the the size of the image, he will simply cut the labels at the end.

Comment: Myabe try "coord diagram"? See example from [ggraph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggraph/vignettes/Layouts.html) package.

Comment: Using my dendrogram object on the function suggested in the linkt you gave, resulted in the error: could not find function "layout_dendrogram_linear". In which package can I find this function?

Comment: You could transform the distance matrix you give to hclust (for example, use sqrt or log), so to emphasize the size of the lower branches.

Comment: How would I do that?